# how to run redvelvet (ruby application) on browser?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find an offline form building application similar to typeform. On exploring I found 'Redvelvet' in typeform github repositiries written in ruby. I have downloaded the ZIP but I dont know how to run it on browser.
Kindly help.

Comment: Assuming this is the code you found https://github.com/Typeform/redvelvet it doesn't seem to do a lot; doesn't have any .rb files in it. Assume it's a part of a bigger framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pay attention to the Gemfile:

`gem 'headless'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.47.1'
gem 'watir-webdriver'
gem 'page-object'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rspec-expectations'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'json'
gem 'dotenv'`

This code doesn't have any web server bundled with it, so you can't run it in your web browser.